# didSelectRow UIPicker

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker (which loads as UIview when I click on a textbox control) I want the textbox to be populated with the values of the UIPicker as I scroll through them. Is this possible, I think the code should be placed in didSelectRow, but not quite sure how to do it.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Problem solved....

route.text = [list objectAtIndex:row];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.... route.text = [list objectAtIndex:row];